# Difference between GMM and mixture of Gaussian processes

Tags: process, model, gaussian

There are quite a few GMM (Gaussian Mixture Model) implementations packages available which model each component as a multivariate Gaussian distribution. If I want to model each component as a Gaussian Process, what do I have to change? Can I take advantage of any of the GMM implementation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.